# How can I use onedrive in elementary

Tags: storage

I want use onedrive as my cloud storage, I've found this (http://xmodulo.com/sync-microsoft-onedrive-linux.html) on the web but the program doesn't support elementary OS.
If i could not find a way, I have no choose but changing my distro to mint
tnx

Comment: Does Mint have a onedrive client now? I think not...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fix the `./install.sh` script at line 40 from

```
    elementaryos|debian|ubuntu|linuxmint|raspbian)
```

to

```
    elementary|debian|ubuntu|linuxmint|raspbian)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few OneDrive clients out there. Might want to give these two a try:

[OneDrive-d](https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d-old) and

[OneDrive Free Client](https://github.com/skilion/onedrive)

Keep in mind that I have not tried either of these as I do not use OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

I installed [OneDrive FreeClient](https://github.com/skilion/onedrive) a few minutes ago as suggested above.
The Git Hub website is pretty much clear about the path to prepare the installation.

The one step is not that clear is running the OneDrive file (`./onedrive`), and after authorizing the app, (click on the URL the app generates and then pasting back on the Terminal the blank page URI) it starts downloading your info.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed this

https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

And it works fine. You just need to follow every step in order.

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand.